# Change key bindings in tmux copy mode

Tags: command-line, tmux

I want to change the key binding in tmux copy mode. This is my tmux config:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

So I use the vi keybindings for copy mode. But since I use the colemak keyboard layout which has the keys <kbd>n</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>,<kbd>i</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd> instead of <kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd> I want to bind the following:

```
bind n down
bind e up
bind h left
bind i right
```

I know how binding keys works but I don't know how the key command for <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `tmux list-keys`:

```
bind-key  -T copy-mode  Up     send-keys  -X  cursor-up
bind-key  -T copy-mode  Down   send-keys  -X  cursor-down
bind-key  -T copy-mode  Left   send-keys  -X  cursor-left
bind-key  -T copy-mode  Right  send-keys  -X  cursor-right
```

So in your case you can do:

```
bind-key  -T copy-mode-vi  n  send-keys Down
bind-key  -T copy-mode-vi  e  send-keys Up
bind-key  -T copy-mode-vi  h  send-keys Left
bind-key  -T copy-mode-vi  i  send-keys Right
```

Comment: thanks it worked! although I don't understand how you got the solution from `tmux list-keys` since there it is called *cursor-up* and so on.

Comment: I did. I still don't get it. Sorry.

Comment: @lukaskitsche To be honest, I had to try it a couple of ways until I hit on the correct form. But the point of giving you the `tmux list-keys` method was so you know where to look for other mappings you may want to do, now that you have the form.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will look at it more deeply when I need it next time.